# iOS analog of java developer signature

Tags: java, ios, code-signing, udid

Is there a way in iOS to uniquely identify **developer** like it is done in java through **package name and developer signature**. I know that in iOS 7 there is **identifierForVendor** that has same value for all of the apps of the same vendor, but the problem is on different devices the VendorID is different regardless developer as explained [here](http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the vendor of an app you inspect the app's bundle identifier. It's in Java-style reverse domain name style (I'm not sure whether it's enforced by Apple right now, but I haven't seen it any other way). You can do that via the app's `Info.plist`.

If you have access to its bundle somehow:

```
plutil -p SomeApp.app/Info.plist
```

The part you're interested is the `CFBundleIdentifier`. You can also query it in code at runtime (if you're providing a library/framework, for example):

```
NSString *bundleId = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]; returns app Id not Vendor Id. I have to identify the vendor on server side, and in this case anyone can create another Xcode project with same bundleID and push a request to server which would be wrong.

Comment: The vendor is part of the bundle ID. At least when releasing to the App Store, nobody can use your part. For example, I can release apps with bundle IDs `net.darkdust.foo`, but I cannot submit an app with bundle ID `com.stackoverflow.foo`. You can do this when releasing an In-House App (one that is not distributed via Apple's App Store). Do you consider this to be a real issue? Apart from the bundle ID, there is no other (reliable) information about the vendor I'm aware of, short of parsing `embedded.mobileprovision` and decoding the embedded certificate.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I parse developer certificate under <data> element from embedded.provison. Does it signifies the vendor of the app? like in java.